# Instagram media image url http://distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com slowdown error

Tags: amazon-s3, instagram, instagram-api

I stored the instagram image url by calling some api (profile pic, media etc) from last 3 year. I analysed that before 2014 its url like  distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com and currently its https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/ (that work fine) but the perviously stored image url  with "distilleryimage7.s3.amazonaws.com" are not accessible its gives error  [Screen shots of s3 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5iqv.png)
Please suggest what we need to do to resolve this